# Skipping line as parsing - Python CSV

Tags: python, bash, csv, logging

Currently my log file is structured like this.

```
Time: 13 s. Month: jul Date: 5
Money: 50. Tires: 0 Rent: yes 
Time: 13 s. Month: jul Date: 5
Money: 50. Tires: 0 Rent: yes 
Time: 13 s. Month: jul Date: 5
Money: 50. Tires: 0 Rent: yes
```

I am writing a python script that converts this into a csv.

```
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'w') as out_file, open('stats.log', 'r') as in_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(['month', 'rent'])

    for line in in_file:
        columns = line[:-1].split(' ')
        columns[6] = ' '.join(columns[6:])
        writer.writerow(columns[:7])
```

I am trying to just create two column for month and rent, but since I'm looking at it in terms of lines, I am having trouble figuring out how to maybe skip line or just look for key words to create a csv file.

Comment: What lines do you want to skip?  What key words are you looking for?

Comment: I am looking to just strip this with the data of MONTH and RENT, and ignore everything else

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv
with open('output.csv', 'w') as out_file, open('stats.log', 'r') as in_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(['month', 'rent'])
    lines = in_file.rstrip().split("\n")
    lines = [lines[x*2]+lines[x*2+1] for x in range(int(len(lines)/2))]
    
    for line in lines:
        columns = line.rstrip().split()
        writer.writerow([columns[1],columns[5]])
```

Comment: Hello, yep but since the data Im looking for is in two different lines (month and rent) the CSV file creates the point but skips a line every time in the spreadsheet

Comment: or lets say that Im looking just to read the Month data. How would I skip a line of data from the log file.